# Custom URL Structure for posts with subcategories

Tags: posts, customization, urls

I have a website with the following structure in Posts:

14k-gold-silver
   - Symphony
   - Noir
14k-gold-diamond
   -forever classic
   -bridal

Now I added some itemes to each of the sub categories shown above. I want the URL structure as:

For symphony: www.mysite.com/jewelry/14k-gold-silver/symphony
Product Sym1: www.mysite.com/jewelry/14k-gold-silver/symphony/sym1

For Noir: www.mysite.com/jewelry/14k-gold-silver/noir
Product Noir1: www.mysite.com/jewelry/14k-gold-silver/symphony/noir1

I am getting the URLs as:

For symphony: www.mysite.com/jewelry/category/14k-gold-silver/symphony
Product Sym1: www.mysite.com/jewelry/sym1

For Noir: www.mysite.com/jewelry/category/14k-gold-silver/noir
Product Noir1: www.mysite.com/jewelry/noir1

How can I get the URLs as mentioned above?

I have set the permalinks as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Try `/jewelry/%category%/%postname%`

Comment: I have already tried this option ... But did not work...

Comment: Also why i am getting /category/ in the url?